# Many to Many Query Buider Symfony2

Tags: symfony, orm, many-to-many, query-builder

I have two entities. Category and Product. They mapped ManyToMany.

```
class Category
{
    ...

   /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    ...

}
```

and Product class

```
class Product
{
    ...

   /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\MyBundle\Entity\Category", inversedBy="name")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    private $category;
}


    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppMyBundle:Product');
    $product = $repository->createQueryBuilder('product')
             ->where('product.category = ?1')->setParameter(1, $variable)
             ->getQuery()->getResult()
```

How to I get result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `join()` method to join products with category entity and then add your filter criteria in `where()` part

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppMyBundle:Product');
$product = $repository->createQueryBuilder('product')
    ->join('product.category','c')          
    ->where('c.id = ?1')
    ->setParameter(1, $variable)
    ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

I have used id of category for filtering if you need to filter with different property then change `c.id` => `c.any other property`

Comment: What is the 'c'?   category?

Comment: @Akim Have you take a look at the doc ?

Comment: @Akim its an alias to category entity a short name